# Why does the fs.inode-max kernel tunable not exist on version 2.6 of the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, inode, documentation, kernel-parameters

The following output (from a Vagrant VM running CentOS 6.6) mostly speaks for itself:

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo 131072 > /proc/sys/fs/inode-max
-bash: /proc/sys/fs/inode-max: No such file or directory
[root@localhost ~]# sysctl -q -p
[root@localhost ~]# echo 'fs.inode-max = 131072' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
[root@localhost ~]# sysctl -q -p
error: "fs.inode-max" is an unknown key
[root@localhost ~]# man proc | col -b | grep -A6 '/proc/sys/fs/inode-max$'
       /proc/sys/fs/inode-max
        This  file  contains the maximum number of in-memory inodes.  On
        some (2.4) systems, it may not be present.  This value should be
        3-4 times larger than the value in file-max, since stdin, stdout
        and network sockets also need an inode to handle them.  When you
        regularly run out of inodes, you need to increase this value.

[root@localhost ~]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 04:27:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@localhost ~]#
```

How to reconcile the man page statement that implies this won't exist *on 2.4 kernels,* with the fact that it doesn't exist on this 2.6 kernel?

Comment: It doesn't exist on 2.4 or higher kernels.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, ha!  Please post that as an answer (with some reference or demonstrated proof).  I was thinking this was a *new* tunable, not an old deprecated one.  And was worried about having to configure it when I tweaked fs.file-max!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page in man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and in Debian has a more useful description:

> `/proc/sys/fs/inode-max` (only present until Linux 2.2)
>
> This  file  contains the maximum number of in-memory inodes.  This value should be 3-4 times larger than the value in file-max, since stdin, stdout and network sockets also need an inode to handle them.  When you regularly run out of inodes, you need to increase this value.
>
> Starting with Linux 2.4, there is no longer a static limit on the number of inodes, and this file is removed.

Based on the last sentence, it's not there since it's not needed.